# Make a short ListView (that doesn't scroll) react to scroll attempts

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with a varying number of items. It can either scroll, or fit on one screen. When the user taps and drags the list, and overscrolls, you get the nice overscroll edge glow effect.

If the list doesn't scroll, because it only has few elements, but you tap and drag one of the items, you still get the edge glow effect. This is nice and what I want.

The problem is if you click *below* the last item, and drag, nothing happens. I want it to 'try to scroll' in that case too. It's confusing if there is no visual feedback, and the list seems frozen.

```
+--------------------------+
| Item 1           (x)     |     Tap and drag here works.  The list
+--------------------------+     doesn't move, but the user gets a
| Item 2                   |     visual overscroll indicator on the
+--------------------------+     top or the bottom.
| Item 3                   |
+--------------------------+
|                          |
|                  (x)     |     Tap and drag here does nothing.
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
```

How can I make the whole ListView react to scroll attempts?

I made sure that it covers all available space, and not just the space needed for the items (set `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` and tried a different BG color just to be sure). Where is the code that initiates the scrolling? It's fine if I have to override something, as I'm already using my own ListView subclass.

Comment: What is the motivation for this? Seeing a list that doesn't take up the whole screen should be enough of an indication to the user that they are seeing the end of the list.

Comment: The problem is not that the user doesn't know if they're at the end. While developing the app, I was scolling around in different views. I encountered a view with only one item, and when I tried to scroll that, I had no visual feedback (but I did have overscroll feedback in a short list with 5 items). The problem is, I thought I had crashed the app! I restarted it a couple of times and even tried to debug it, before I realized I just have been tapping in a dead area.

Comment: Well, if your app isn't crashing, and if regular Android users won't find it odd (because it's the standard platform behavior), then I'm not really sure what needs to be fixed here. If you really wanted to, perhaps you could subclass ListView and have it automatically add a footer view with the height of the remaining space, but I really think it's unnecessary (and probably more complicated than it sounds).

Answer (score 0):

Found it out. The following in a ListView subclass will do the trick. I tested it on Android 4.2.1, but it should work on any 4.x.

**Disclaimer: This code relies on implementation details of the ListView and uses reflection do modify private variables. I can't overstate how evil this is. You shouldn't use this in production code!**

I made this as a proof of concept and to satisfy my curiosity. If you want to use code like this (unfortunately it is sometimes neccessary to get certain effects), put version guards around it, as I do below. Only run on versions you tried it on and have checked the source code for. In other cases, you should use just call the default behavoir, e.g.`return super.onTouchEvent(ev)`.

This code allows you do (unsuccessfully attempt to) scroll a short list by the empty part below the last item. Click and drag in the white space and you should see the overscroll glow. This is especially cool if you have implemented a iPhone like overscroll rubberband effect.

How does it work? Look at [AbsListView.OnTouchEvent](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/AbsListView.java/#3343). In line 3397, motionPosition is the currently selected item index. If it is -1 (no item), the `if` a few lines later is false, and `mTouchMode` doesn't get set. In that case, I put the ListView manually into scrolling mode.

```
static final int TOUCH_MODE_DOWN = 0;
static final int TOUCH_MODE_SCROLL = 3;
static final int TOUCH_MODE_FLING = 4;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN ||
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        final int x = (int) ev.getX();
        final int y = (int) ev.getY();
        int motionPosition = pointToPosition(x, y);
        int action = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK);

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (motionPosition == -1) {
                setFieldInt("mActivePointerId", ev.getPointerId(0));
                if (!getAdapterViewFieldBool("mDataChanged")) {
                    if ((getFieldInt("mTouchMode") != TOUCH_MODE_FLING)) {
                        setFieldInt("mTouchMode", TOUCH_MODE_DOWN);
                    }
                }

                setFieldInt("mMotionViewOriginalTop", 0);
                setFieldInt("mMotionX", x);
                setFieldInt("mMotionY", y);
                setFieldInt("mMotionPosition", motionPosition);
                setFieldInt("mLastY", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

private void setFieldInt(String fieldName, int value) {
    try {
        Field field = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.setInt(this, value);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) { Log.v(TAG, "exception", e); }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) { Log.v(TAG, "exception", e); }
}

private int getFieldInt(String fieldName) {
    try {
        Field field = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.getInt(this);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) { Log.v(TAG, "exception", e); }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) { Log.v(TAG, "exception", e); }
    return 0;
}


private boolean getAdapterViewFieldBool(String fieldName) {
    try {
        Field field = AdapterView.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.getBoolean(this);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) { Log.v(TAG, "exception", e); }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) { Log.v(TAG, "exception", e); }
    return false;
}
```